# Произвольные цвета при выделении, если для страницы заданы свойства «background» и «color»

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selection

### 1. Цель

Задать произвольный цвет выделяемому тексту и его фону, если для страницы уже прописаны цвета для фона и текста, отличные от стандартных. Приветствуется любое решение, которое ничего не портит.

---

---

### 2. Минимальный пример кода

```css
body {
  background: sienna;
  color: pink;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

::selection {
  background: moccasin;
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
Не принять мне итоги, чья щемит прямота. Отречений дороги заведут в никуда. Ты — цветок Поднебесья, Ты — улыбка в ночи, эхо сладостных песен и Венеры лучи. Ты — колибри прекрасный, Амазонки сапфир, — дочь природы несчастной в звуках музыки лир. Личность
мерно теряешь, изучая Тебя. Сон, еду забываешь, без сознанья Любя.
```

[**Он же на Codepen.io**](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/WoOYeV). Для Firefox, [**по-видимому**](https://css-tricks.com/window-inactive-styling/), не поддерживается подсветка выделенного текста в неактивном окне.

---

---

### 3. Желаемое поведение

У [**псевдоэлемента ::-moz-selection**](http://xiper.net/manuals/css-extensions/mozilla/pseudo-classes-elements/moz-selection) фон выделенного текста — `rgb(255, 228, 181)`, что [**соответствует указанному мной цвету moccasin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names). Протестировано в Firefox.

[image: moz-selection]

---

---

### 4. Актуальное поведение

Но у [**псевдоэлемента ::selection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) фон выделенного текста — `rgb(216, 158, 096)`. Получается плохо. Протестировано в Chrome и Opera.

[image: selection]

Если убрать в приведённом выше коде `background: sienna; color: pink;`, то цвета для выделения в Chrome и Opera отображаются нормально.

[image: selection без фона]

Но если задать для тега `body` свойства `background` и `color`, то выделенные цвета становятся неправильными, будто происходит наложение цветов. Как его убрать, нагуглить не удалось.

---

---

### 5. Попытки решения

1. Указание цвета вместо [**X11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names) в других форматах ничего не изменило.
2. Применение атрибута `contenteditable`, как [**советуют**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14506434/5951529) на Stack Overflow, тоже ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фоновый цвет выделения в Хроме имеет некую степень прозрачности, поэтому вам надо указать свой цвет в формате RGBA, **задав степень непрозрачности меньше 100%**:

```
::selection {
  background: rgba(255, 228, 181, 0.99);
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

В данном случае `255, 228, 181` соответствует указанному вами цвету `moccasin`.

```css
body {
  background: sienna;
  color: pink;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
 
::selection {
  background: rgba(255, 228, 181, 0.99);
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
Не принять мне итоги, чья щемит прямота. Отречений дороги заведут в никуда. Ты — цветок Поднебесья, Ты — улыбка в ночи, эхо сладостных песен и Венеры лучи. Ты — колибри прекрасный, Амазонки сапфир, — дочь природы несчастной в звуках музыки лир. Личность
мерно теряешь, изучая Тебя. Сон, еду забываешь, без сознанья Любя.
```

Живой пример на JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/terron/nrwjLkbm/](http://jsfiddle.net/terron/nrwjLkbm/)

**Результат в Chrome:**

[image: Результат в Chrome]

**Результат в Firefox:**

[image: Результат в Firefox]

Comment: terron, у `::selection` и `::moz-selection` разное поведение не в пользу `::selection`. `::selection` выделяет также картинки и шрифты. См. результаты в [**Firefox**](http://i.imgur.com/zz1Ze5B.png) и [**Chrome**](http://i.imgur.com/XapvCAs.png). Если в случае с картинками можно задать `background: transparent`, то как отменить или кастомизировать выделение шрифтов, подключённых через Cufon, не понимаю.

Comment: [**Код**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/technical_texts/cufon_test.html) — [**результат выполнения**](http://kristinita.ru/technical_texts/cufon_test.html), неважный в Chrome. Выложил на сайт, поскольку Codepen не пропускает Cufon. // Поэтому и отклонил Вашу правку и пока не принял (плюс поставил) Ваш ответ: может, на JavaScript найдётся лучшее решение, нормально выделяющее шрифты. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, решить проблему с прозрачностью от части можно, подобрав такой цвет, который будет отображаться как `moccasin` при 50% прозрачности. Проблему с кривым выделением на Cufon не смогли решить даже на [официальном сайте](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), где выделение слов залезает друг на друга. С другой стороны, если вы допускаете, что кто-то будет выделять или копировать текст на вашем сайте, я бы порекомендовал вам отказаться от Cufon ради UX и использовать более традиционные и православные методы подгрузки шрифтов.

Comment: terron, да, знаю, что Cufon — устаревшее решение, но много менять придётся. В Firefox шрифты [**вообще не выделяются**](http://i.imgur.com/V8S2LFF.png). Только как реализовать это для других браузеров, не нагуглю. Спасибо.